# Unix how to loop through directories, send output to another directory with base name of input file

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, filenames

I am an infrequent user of UNIX, I'm sure this will be fairly trivial for any regular user so I appologize for that. I have the following code:

```
 for file in /home/sub1/samples/aaa*/*_novoalign.bam
      do
           samtools depth -r chr9:218026635-21994999 *_novoalign.bam < $file > /home/sub2/sub3/${file}.out 
      done
```

I was hoping the output would be sent to a file in sub2/sub3/ with its name like the input folder. It says 'no file or directory'. I would ideally like to send it here with the '_novoalign.bam' removed and a new ending eg '_output.txt' added. Any tips?

p.s. I don't have permission to write to the directory in which the input file is found.

Comment: I guess the `*_novoalign.bam` in the `samtools` call is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the path and then the extension you don't want:

```
base=${file##*/}
newfile=${base%_novoalign.bam}_output.txt
```

Then use:

```
... > "/home/sub2/sub3/$newfile"
```

Check out Shell Parameter Expansion here for other options:

[GNU Bash Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/sub1/samples
for file in aaa*/*_novoalign.bam; do
    target_file="${file%_novoalign.bam}_output.txt"
    samtools depth -r chr9:218026635-21994999 <"$file" >"$target_file"
done
```